# preserve hidden attribute on directory when using tar

Tags: windows, windows-11, tar

Here is the shell script I'm writing to automate the task of copying a specific Vue project to another location on a Windows 11 machine:

```
# declare and initialize variables
source="/z/files/development/vue/code/project17"
target="/c/users/knot22/desktop/temp_dev"

# display contents of variables to user; ask user whether or not to proceed; act accordingly
echo -e "\nCopy from: ${source}"
echo -e   "Copy to:   ${target}\n"

read -p "Proceed? (y/n) " proceed
echo

if [[ ${proceed^^} == Y ]]; then    
    IFS='/' read -ra PARTS <<< "${source#/}"        # split $source string, without leading /, into array called PARTS using / as delimiter
    arrayLength="${#PARTS[@]}"
    tar -c --exclude="node_modules" -C / "${source#/}" | tar -x -C "/${target#/}" --strip-components="$(($arrayLength - 1))"
    echo -e "Copy operation is complete\n"
else
    echo -e "Operation aborted\n"
fi
```

It copies everything to the new location except the `node_modules` directory, which is how it's intended to behave.  There is an improvement to be made though.  The `.git` directory in the source location is hidden but when it's copied over to the target location the hidden attribute is not carried along.  Is there a way to retain that attribute?  I searched man tar but didn't find anything that addressed preserving the hidden attribute.

Comment: I assume this is on a Windows system (since Linux doesn't have a "hidden" attribute)?

Comment: Yes, Windows 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tar doesn't support the "hidden" filesystem attribute. `tar` was created 43 years ago to make backups of Unix systems to tape (*t*ape *ar*chive). Hidden files on Unix are files that start with a `.` in the file name, and thus there was no need for Unix filesystems (or utilities) to support such a flag.

Tar doesn't even have a metadata field that would support this feature. In fact, GNU tar doesn't even support Linux-style acls.

As stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)):
[image: tar format]

As an alternative, you can set the hidden attribute after the copy, using the `attrib` Windows utility. It also seems like `rsync` supports hidden files (haven't confirmed myself). Using `rsync` would seem like a better idea anyways, since it's created for copying complex directory structures.